# How to handle null values when using TYPE operator in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to use the type of an entity in a query but this field can be null.

This is an example of my query

```
SELECT TYPE(e.job)
FROM Employee e
```

The problem is that e.job might be null and I get this exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve discriminator value [null] to entity name.

Could someone please tell me how to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this

```
SELECT TYPE(e.job) FROM Employee e WHERE e.job IS NOT NULL
```

as your JPA query.